# Why isn't my method being called?

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm running a C# project compiled against .NET 3.5 in VS 2010 SP 1 on a Windows 8 machine with .NET 4.5 installed, if that matters.

I have a method that looks like the following:

```
private IEnumerable<TModel> ExecuteAndGet<TModel>(string name, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
        where TModel : new()
{ // <-- Breakpoint 1

    // Non-trivial code so I doubt the method call is being optimized away
    // Or something if that's even possible.
}
```

In the same class in a different method I call `ExecuteAndGet` like so:

```
this.ExecuteAndGet<object>("[dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure]", parameters); // <-- Breakpoint 2
```

That's definitely the only overload of that method.  While running the program in debug mode I hit breakpoint 2.  I've tried just regular "F5" and "Step INTO" but it completely skips going inside the method altogether and it skips breakpoint 1.  I have no idea why this is happening.  Other calls to `ExecuteAndGet` are working and I don't see why this is any different. Help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the code? It may be being caused by something you think is working

Comment: are you sure that you have done a build? Try to do a `Clean` and then a `build` of your project and see if that helps

Comment: Do you get some error or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually enumerating. Try:

```
this.ExecuteAndGet<object>("[dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure]", parameters).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The enumerable returned is implemented as an iterator block. Code inside iterator blocks does not actually execute until they are enumerated for the first time, e.g. add call `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`