# How to throw exception from a method with generic return type

Tags: c#, generics, exception

While building an extension method for obtaining the value of attributes I have the following method signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetAttributeValues<TAttribute, TValue>(
      this Type type,
      string methodName,
      Type[] parameterTypes,
      Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector,
      bool inherit = false) where TAttribute : Attribute
```

However, during testing I've found that I cannot usefully throw an exception inside this method. If I throw an instance of `ArgumentException` the execution process appears to ignore it, *i.e.*, the exception doesn't bubble up. A `try... catch` in the calling method catches nothing.

If I call `GetType()` on the result of the method call, the type is presented as the fully-qualified name of the method.

I also can't step into the method while debugging.

Can anyone explain why I'm unable to stop the application with an exception, even if all this method does is throw an exception?

Comment: Please show the full code of your method. If it is an enumerator block (using yield), it is only executed when you iterate through the returned `IEnumerable` (and the exception is thrown onyl then, and not before returning from your method). And show how you called `GetType()`, maybe you did not call it on the result but on the method(-group) itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your extension method is returning an `IEnumerable<T>` you need to call something like `ToArray` or `First` on it otherwise it won't enumerate.

Comment: Aw jeez, what a rookie mistake to make. How embarrassing.

Comment: @awj: I made the same mistake, myself, [including asking a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142772/why-isnt-my-method-being-called) here.  Of course I learned from it!  No shame :)